# Synonyms for word composite in Solr 4.4

Tags: solr, lucene, solr4, dspace

I need to do some research using a synonym in Solr 4.4. When I configure the search for synonyms with simple words, it works normally, but when used a composite synonym it does not work. Ideas to solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "it does not work"? What issues are you experiencing?

Comment: For example, I have files indexed in Solr that are retrieved when we search using some acronyms, such as "PRT". I created synonyms for these same documents to be retrieved by searching for "Portaria" and this works perfectly. However, the same does not happen when I need to search for these acronyms using compound words, as we see in the example in the image, "Ato regimental" is not returning files with the acronym "ATR" and it should.

Comment: I see. Yes, multi-word synonyms are hard to get right. From what I understand applying synonyms at index time (rather than query time) is one way to get this to work: See https://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2013/10/27/why-is-multi-term-synonyms-so-hard-in-solr/ and https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters-solr.SynonymFilterFactory

Comment: Please don't add text content as screenshots - it makes it hard to search and near impossible to read for those with accessibility issues.